# Count of flag value 1 between two flag values 0s

Tags: tableau-api

I have the flag column which has 0 and 1 values.
I want to count the 1s between two 0s
flag
0
0
1
1
0
1
1
1
Expected output
0
0
1
2
0
1
2
3

Comment: Looks like a running sum thing - but you'll need some sort of flag to instruct the running sum to restart every 0

Comment: You can use LOD expression to achieve this (might need to group data, depending on your data set).